# Talend: Copy data from one SQL database to another

Tags: talend

I want to copy data from one database to another database using Talend. How do I do that?

(Note: Before copying the data I need to delete data from the destination database first.)

Comment: Your question is missing lots of necessary information. What do you mean by delete first? That you need to delete some data and then copy the partial data set to the new database? Or that you simply want the copied data to be removed from the source database? Does it need to be done first or just at the same time? What database is the source and what is the target? And is there anything particularly special about the data?

Comment: By delete first I meant in my destination database I want only source's database's data. Already existing data in destination's database need to be deleted before copying from the source.

I am using SQL server database.

Comment: In this case you can do that with a `Drop table if exists and create` option on the DB output component. I've added an answer with some more detail.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete data from destination tables then use simple expression of delete and use this sql expression in tSQLRow component to execute. then you can refer below component to transform whole database with schema or without schema.

please check [tTransferDatabase](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/?eid=457&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1) component on exchange it is very well for transform database.

Comment: Thanks,
I will give it a try and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

As clarified in your comments you want to clear your target database before loading the new data from your source database.

To this end you just want to connect a database input component (such as tOracleInput) - with your appropriate SELECT query and configured schema in Talend - to a database output component (such as tMysqlOutput) and then change the `Action on table` option to "Drop table if exists and create".

This will drop any pre-existing table of the same name and create a new one with the schema in the Talend component. You'll have to add any keys and auto-increment on columns with a database row component (such as tMysqlRow) with an alter table script as you would directly on the database.